# How do I set an LXC container to start on boot in 15.10?

Tags: lxc, lxd

15.10 uses the new db based config system. Getting this done requires adding a directive to the container's config using `lxc config edit containernanme`. Problem is I can't find the config docs (15.10 edition) anywhere.

There is a lot of information on the old file based config.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Update your LXD from lxd stable ppa: https://launchpad.net/~ubuntu-lxc/+archive/ubuntu/lxd-stable and update LXD.
2. lxd is in development now (to be launched stable in 16.04 LTS launch) you can check the doc config in github: https://github.com/lxc/lxd/blob/master/specs/configuration.md, you can read here that you need config boot.autostart parameter

> `lxc config set machine boot.autostart true`